# there is some space left after applying background-size : cover; property

Tags: html, css

Some spaces left in web page after applying css property:
[image: some space left in web page after applying css property]

CSS Code:
[image: CSS Code]

Comment: What you need? that white strip at the bottom?

Comment: @– user3733831 i want to display image on full page

Comment: Kindly provide code or codepen link so that we can work on it.

Comment: @– Sana Mumtaz sure wait for the moment.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, possibly on whatever browser/system you are using the body is not given any height by default, you can check this in your browser devtools by inspecting the body and looking at computed height.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your CSS should be work. Try this... I added `height: 100%` to `body`.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```